# gradle - Could not determine java version from '11.0.4'

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle 6.3 and Java 11.0.4. I have set JAVA_HOME variable. I am able to run Gradle sometimes, but sometimes it failing with the below exception.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.4'.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '11.0.4'.
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:257)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:191)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

Gradle version:

```
gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-03-24 19:52:07 UTC
Revision:     bacd40b727b0130eeac8855ae3f9fd9a0b207c60

Kotlin:       1.3.70
Groovy:       2.5.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.4 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.4+11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

command used:

```
gradle -DskipCompile=true -Dchs.build.skiptestexports=true -Dtestlist.path=G:/code/testjobs.windows/job.185.txt runtestsonlyqg -b G:/code/top_src/tests/build.gradle
```

Comment: What command are you running that results in the build failure? Also maybe you're using `gradlew` (which might have a different version than your system-wide `gradle` installation).

Comment: I am running a test target. command used: 
gradle -DskipCompile=true -Dchs.build.skiptestexports=true -Dtestlist.path=G:/code/testjobs.windows/job.185.txt runtestsonlyqg -b G:/code/top_src/tests/build.gradle

Comment: It _might_ be the jdk version causing the issue... Just to rule it out, maybe try to use a more recent minor version of jdk 11 e.g. 11.0.6 (or alternatively to an older one if you just recently upgraded).

Comment: _sometimes it failing with the below execption._ :  If this is to do with JDK, it should fail all the times?  Any thing that adds to "intermittent" behavior (such as Shared directories for data)?